# Django calculate mean of two field from a dataset in views.py

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a dataset with the population of men and women by years. I want to calculate the mean. Specifically (men+women)/2 for 2018 and so on. See my code example below:

```py
views.py

def Nufus_ilce(request):
    dataset = models.population.objects.all()

    means =

    context = {
        'dataset': dataset,
        'means': means,
    }
    return render(request, 'population.html', context)



population.html

{{ dataset.year }}
{{ dataset.man }}
{{ dataset.woman }}
{{ means }}
```

So how do I calculate means?

Comment: Would it be possible to give an example of what `dataset` is expected to look like?

Comment: So the `means` is an aggregate over *all* years? Or do you want the mean *per* year?

Comment: Seems like something from [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-over-a-queryset) could be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of making a new queryset, you can *annotate* the original one, like:

```
from django.db.models import F

def Nufus_ilce(request):
    dataset = models.population.objects.annotate(
        mean=(F('man') + F('woman'))/2
    )
    context = {
        'dataset': dataset,
    }
    return render(request, 'population.html', context)
```

We now thus can render this with:

```
{% for item in dataset %}
    {{ item.year }}
    {{ item.man }}
    {{ item.woman }}
    {{ item.mean }}
{% endfor %}
```